# Display custom post using ID

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

In my theme, I have a custom post type called sliders. Here the user is allowed to upload images in a `meta-box`. So, the images are saved as meta data in `wp_post_meta` table.

Now what I want to do is, displaying a slider using its ID.

I did like following but no result

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=sliders&p=411');

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
   while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
   the_post();
 endwhile;
}
```

This doesn't display anything. No even errors. Anyway, If I used `the_title()` instead of `the_post()`, it shows the title of the slider fine. Same for the `the_author()` It shows the author without error.

Why is this weird ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: deleted incorrect information

I see what you are missing now. Without knowing the specifics, I tried to point you in the right direction with this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=sliders&p=411');

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

        // Get the specific meta data for the current post
        $saved_slider_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slider_meta_key' );

        // Echo the data
        echo $saved_slider_meta;

    endwhile;

    // Restore original post data if there are other loops
    wp_reset_post_data();
}
```

Here is more information about [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: That string syntax is correct in context

Comment: Thanks so I can't get the post directly. I have to call meta details seperately... :) OK I'll try that!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=sliders&p=411');
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

    $slider_imgs = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slider_meta_key' );

    foreach($slider_imgs as $slider_img)
    {
       echo '<img src="'.$saved_slider_meta.'">';
    }
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_post_data();
}
```

Check documentation of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/)